# Export combination of function and namespace in Typescript 2

Tags: typescript, knex.js

This question is motivated by the [Types 2.0 Knex Declarations](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/knex/index.d.ts).

After reading the [Typescript-Handbook Declaration Files Deep Dive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/declaration%20files/Deep%20Dive.md) I am still unable to understand what is going wrong or how to fix the issue.

In that the Knex.js type declarations, there are 3 declarations of the same name followed by an export of that name:

```
interface Knex extends Knex.QueryInterface { /*...*/ }

declare function Knex(config: Knex.Config): Knex;

declare namespace Knex { /*..*/ }

export = Knex;
```

When I import Knex like:

```
import * as Knex from 'knex';
```

I would expect to have access to the Knex function, interface type, AND namespace. However, my tsc (version 2.0.2 typescript@rc) seems to only be importing the Knex function.

Why am I not able to access the properties of the namespace? Is there a suggested way to change the type declarations such that I would have access to the properties of the namespace?